# Multi page form data validation in Play Framework?

Tags: forms, hibernate, validation, model-view-controller, playframework-2.0

I am a beginner in java play framework. I an building an app which will take form data spread in multiple pages say 4 to 5 pages. But all the data is mapped to same model. How can I get the data uploaded by user per page, validate against my model's constraints, and at the end save whole data in my model.

For ex:- If page 1 has name field which is required, and page 2 has hobbies field which is required. Then how can i specifically validate data filled in that particular page, navigate till last page, and save all the data in model, in last page.

Model would have 60-70 fields.

I am using Hibernate ORM.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could prefill the next form with the values of the last form, save them in the database, go to the next form, load the entered values from the values and pre-fill the next form and so on. For this, use a method in your controller:

```
public static Result fillOutForm1(){
 Hobby form1 = new Hobby("sitting still", "diabetes");
 Form<Hobby > preFilledForm = newHobbyForm.fill(form1);
 return ok(views.html.YOURVIEWCLASS.render(preFilledForm);
}
```

With this you "send" some values to the first view class with a form. In there, the user answers some more fields and hits `Submit`.
So you need a route back to your controller, to handle the new input in routes.conf:

```
GET     /Form1              controllers.Application.fillOutForm1()
POST    /Form1              controllers.Application.sendForm1()
```

This is in your controller class:

```
public static Result sendForm1(){
        Form<Hobby> boundHobby = newHobbyForm.bindFromRequest();
        Hobby newHobby = boundHobby.get();
        //In your hobby class you need a finder implementation, so that you can interact with the database. With save() you put it into the database. This may be different for the database you use!
        newHobby.save();

        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

You can then not redirect to the index, but to the next view class with the next form and there get your last answers from the db, prefill them again and put them into the form. Do this as often as you need.